# Ubuntu "/run" is = to 10% available RAM

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tmpfs

I've noticed that Ubuntu (14.04 and 16.04) creates a `/run` partition depending on the available RAM, and in 3 different servers i've noticed that this value is **always equal to 10% of installed RAM on the server**.

How to correctly bypass this value and increase this `tmpfs` partition on Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: This is off-topic here since it has nothing to do with programming. Try https://unix.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.